# Bind Inner Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, asprepeater

I have the following repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
          ...
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 <asp:Label  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id")%>'> </asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ssdvalue")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("stptime")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </td>
  </tr>      
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
```

Now In above code there are two repeater : repeater1 and repeater2(which is inside the  tag)

For above i have written following code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("sp_data",
         new SqlParameter("@From_Time", "2014-11-01 00:00:00.000"),
         new SqlParameter("@To_Time", "2014-11-03 00:00:00.000"));
    repeater1 .DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    repeater1 .DataBind();
```

This will bind the repeater1.

And for Repeater2 i have written following code:

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("sp_data",
                 new SqlParameter("@From_Time", "2014-11-01 00:00:00.000"),
                 new SqlParameter("@To_Time", "2014-11-03 00:00:00.000"));

            Repeater rpt = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2");
            rpt.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
            rpt.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Now the whole output is coming like :

```
Id    Ssdvalue  stptime
1      112      3 hours 4hours 5 hours 6 hours 12minutes 20minutes
2      234      3 hours 4hours 5 hours 6 hours 12minutes 20minutes
3      450      3 hours 4hours 5 hours 6 hours 12minutes 20minutes
4      987      3 hours 4hours 5 hours 6 hours 12minutes 20minutes
5      456      3 hours 4hours 5 hours 6 hours 12minutes 20minutes
6      091      3 hours 4hours 5 hours 6 hours 12minutes 20minutes
```

But this above output is not correct.

```
I want output like Below:

   Id    Ssdvalue  stptime
    1      112      3 hours
    2      234      4hours
    3      450      5 hours
    4      987      6 hours
    5      456      12minutes
    6      091      20minutes
```

So how can i get the above output?

Comment: Your HTML is malformed cause you have nested repeated inside one another. I suggest if you replace child repeater with a gridview.

Comment: In the Repeater1_ItemDataBound you are binding each Repeater2 to the same DataSet every time - you need to filter this on whatever the relationship between the 2 is. i.e how do you know the Repeater Row with the Id of 1 should display the stptime of 3 hours?

Comment: both have the same number of row output from ds.table[0] and ds.tables[1].

Comment: @deepak - But you can't expect it to be smart enough and map them automatically. You need to provide any link right so that it will map 1 to 1?

Comment: ok but how can i do that? how can i map ?

Comment: @deepak We can't tell you that with the information you have given - you need to be a bit more specific about the relationship between the 2 - what is the DB structure? What does "sp_data" do?

Comment: both have the same `id`

Comment: @deepak In theory then it is simple, what you need to do is in your Repeater1_ItemDataBound - get the Id of the current row then filter the DataSet by the Id before binding to Repeater2. However looking at what you are trying to do this all seems very inefficient - can you not change "sp_data" to do the join and return a complete DataSet so you no longer need Repeater2 at all?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:-

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
          e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
       {
          DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("sp_data",
                 new SqlParameter("@From_Time", "2014-11-01 00:00:00.000"),
                new SqlParameter("@To_Time", "2014-11-03 00:00:00.000"));         
        Label Label1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
        Repeater rpt = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2");
        var source = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<int>("Id") == Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text))
                .Select(x => new 
                      { 
                          stptime= x.Field<DateTime>("stptime")
                      });
       rpt.DataSource = source ;
       rpt.DataBind();
      }
}
```

Since you need to map with same Id, you will have to filter the data based on Id, i.e. `Id` 1 will be mapped to `stpTime` 3 hours and so on. Thus, we need to filter the main data source which I am doing using LINQ `Where` clause, and we are getting the corresponding Id from `Label`.